# Python Pandas - finding duplicate names and telling them apart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

(Somewhat) new to python and coding in general! Using python 3.7 and pandas, I'm running code to create a searchable list of people in my dataframe, and I feel like my way of telling duplicates apart is very roundabout. I would love some advice on making it simpler and more efficient.

I have a database in pandas, 'df2', which has three relevant rows: 'First Name', 'Last Name' and 'People ID'. Some people will have the same name, and these can be told apart by their 'People ID'. I start by making the 'Name' column as thus:

```
df2['Name'] = df2['First Name'] + ' ' + df2['Last Name']
```

Now I make a Dict, nameid, to find out how many different People IDs are associated to each unique 'Name' string.

```
nameid = {}
for i in df2.index:
    try:
        nameid[df2.loc[i, 'Name']].append(df2.loc[i, 'People ID'])
    except:
        nameid[df2.loc[i, 'Name']] = [df2.loc[i, 'People ID']]
```

There are multiple occurences of each person in the spreadsheet, so I want to just have each unique instance of a different 'People ID' using set().

```
for i in nameid.keys():
    nameid[i] = list(set(nameid[i]))
```

Now I create a second dict, namead, which is a "filtered" version of nameid where we've removed all reviewer names with just one ID value associated (those are fine as they are).

```
namead = {}

for i in nameid.keys():
    paceholder = ['Nothing']
    try:
        paceholder.append(nameid[i][1])
        namead[i] = nameid[i]
    except:
        pass
```

Finally, I use namead to make dupes, the list of index values of df2 where there are names belonging to different reviewers. I then pass that through df2 to add the 'People ID' to those names and ensure there is no confusion.

```
dupes = [i for i in df2.index if df2.loc[i, 'Name'] in namead.keys()]
for i in duperevs:
    df2.loc[i, 'Name'] += ' ' + str(df2.loc[i, 'People ID'])
```

Whew! I feel like I added several layers of complexity here but I'm not sure where to start - help would be much appreciated!

EDIT - I'm not sure how to put an extract of the dataframe in this textbox. Clarification: each row of data has information, and I need it to be searchable by name for the end user, with a placeholder to differentiate identical names (the People ID). The resulting data looks like: "Frank Jones / 14498", "Mitin Nutil / 35589", "Maveh Kadini 1433 / 1433" (indicating that there's more than one Maveh Kadini in the data). Each person (by People ID) will appear in many different rows of data.

Comment: Can you give an example dataframe of ~15/20 people and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will comment on the coding, then I will suggest an alternative solution

## Variable naming

Ideally you want your variable names to express what the purpose of a variable is. `nameid` and `df2` are partly understandable, `namead` is not.

## Exception

Never just do `try-except`. Always try to be as specific as possible on the exception. In the creation of `nameid` you except a `KeyError`, and in the other case a `IndexError`. Then use it like that

## `collections.defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault`

Instead of trying and getting the `KeyError`, it is easier to use

```
nameid = defaultdict(list)
for i in df2.index:
    nameid[df2.loc[i, 'Name']].append(df2.loc[i, 'People ID'])
```

would work

## iteration

apart from the fact that you want to prevent iteration as much as possible when using pandas (or numpy), in Python in general, there is almost always a better way than to iterator over the index. In this particular case, you can use `DataFrame.iterrows`. If the column labels had been valid python identifiers, `DataFrame.itertuples` would have been even better

```
nameid = defaultdict(list)
for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    nameid[row['Name']].append(row['People ID'])
```

with `_` being the convention for the name of a variable you don't need

## set

later you do

```
for i in nameid.keys():
    nameid[i] = list(set(nameid[i]))
```

Why not use set from the start, and why the conversion to list afterwards?

```
nameid = defaultdict(set)
for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    nameid[row['Name']].add(row['People ID'])
```

does all you need

## `len`

the next part

```
namead = {}

for i in nameid.keys():
    paceholder = ['Nothing']
    try:
        paceholder.append(nameid[i][1])
        namead[i] = nameid[i]
    except:
        pass
```

uses list indexing `[1]` and expects lists with only 1 element to throw an Exception. This can be expressed a lot simpler with a dict expression. Later it seems the actual ids are not even needed since you only use the keys, so a set expression does the trick.

```
namead = {
    name
    for name, ids in nameid.items()
    if len(ids) > 1
}
```

## pandas indexing

```
dupes = [i for i in df2.index if df2.loc[i, 'Name'] in namead.keys()]
for i in duperevs:
    df2.loc[i, 'Name'] += ' ' + str(df2.loc[i, 'People ID'])
```

`pandas.Series` as an `isin` function, so there is no need to make an intermediate list of keys whose name has more id's

```
dupes = df2["Name"].isin(namead)
df2.loc[dupes, "Name"] += " " + df2["People ID"].astype(str)
```

works too

## Alternative approach

You can also use [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html)

```
dupes = df2.groupby(['Name'])["People ID"].nunique()
```

This is a `Series` with the `Name` as index, and the number of unique `People ID`s as value. Then you can filter those with a value > 1, and check against the name

> ```
> Name
> Jane Doe    1
> John Doe    2
> Name: People ID, dtype: int64
> ```

```
dupes_idx = df2["Name"].isin(dupes[dupes>1].index)
```

Now you just need to append the `People ID`  to the `Name`

```
df2.loc[dupes_idx, "Name"] += " " + df2["People ID"].astype(str)
```

This was tested on

```
data = [
    ["John", "Doe", 1],
    ["John", "Doe", 1],
    ["John", "Doe", 2],
    ["Jane", "Doe", 1],
    ["John", "Doe", 2],
    ["Jane", "Doe", 1],
    ["John", "Doe", 1],
]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['First Name', 'Last Name', 'People ID'])
```

> ```
> First Name    Last Name   People ID   Name
> 0     John    Doe     1   John Doe 1
> 1     John    Doe     1   John Doe 1
> 2     John    Doe     2   John Doe 2
> 3     Jane    Doe     1   Jane Doe
> 4     John    Doe     2   John Doe 2
> 5     Jane    Doe     1   Jane Doe
> 6     John    Doe     1   John Doe 1
> ```

Comment: Thank you! All of this is so useful, and I'm implementing the groupby.nunique() now.

Answer (score 0):

> There are multiple occurences of each person in the spreadsheet, so I want to just have each unique instance of a different 'People ID' using set().

`df.groupby('Name').apply(set)`

> Now I create a second dict, namead, which is a "filtered" version of nameid where we've removed all reviewer names with just one ID value associated (those are fine as they are).

`df.groupby('Name').apply(set).loc[df.groupby('Name').count>1]`

> I then pass that through df2 to add the 'People ID' to those names and ensure there is no confusion.

I think that just doing `df['Name'] =  df['Name']+(' '+'df['People ID'])*(df.groupby('Name').count>1)` will do everything you want, but I recommend just doing `df['Name'] =  df['Name']+' '+'df['People ID']`. That is, you should just add `People ID` to all of the `Name` column, regardless of whether the name is unique. Consistency is generally better than parsimony.